# swiftui textfiled and button inside a button

Tags: swift, swiftui, ios13, xcode11, swift5

I am trying to trigger button when a user clicks background area of a view.
As a solution, I decided to make a button and put the view into the button as a label.
But the Problem is that the button is triggered even on the TextField and sometimes on another button inside.

How can i disable the back button on some views (TextField and Button in this case) I select?

I attach my code below and [rendered preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LAY74.png).

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct ButtonOnbutton: View {
    @State var memo: String = ""
    var body: some View {
        Button(action: {
            print("down button clicked")
        }) {
            VStack(spacing: 10) {
                Text("before")
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                TextField("type memo", text: $memo)
                    .font(.custom("SFProDisplay-Regular", size: 12))
                    .textFieldStyle(RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle())
                Text("after")
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                Button(action: {
                    print("inside button clicked")
                }) {
                    Text("inside button")
                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                }
                .background(Color.red)
            }
        }
        .background(Color.blue)
    .padding()
    }
}

struct buttonOnbutton_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ButtonOnbutton()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I correctly understood your goal then it is better to used `onTapGesture` instead of button, as shown below

```
var body: some View {
    VStack(spacing: 10) {
        Text("before")
            .foregroundColor(.white)
        TextField("type memo", text: $memo)
            .font(.custom("SFProDisplay-Regular", size: 12))
            .textFieldStyle(RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle())
            .onTapGesture {} // << just blocks outer tap
        Text("after")
            .foregroundColor(.white)
        Button(action: {
            print("inside button clicked")
        }) {
            Text("inside button")
                .foregroundColor(.white)
        }
        .background(Color.red)
    }
    .background(Color.blue)
    .onTapGesture {
        print("background area clicked")
    }
    .padding()
}
```

Comment: The idea, adding tapGesture on textField, was that i couldn't come up with. I solved the problem. Thank you!